# PowerShell manifest referencing external assembly

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to register a new PowerShell module just by defining a new module manifest and putting it in the specified directory?

E.g. a a new module named `SampleModule` should be created. I put the empty manifest file `SampleModule.psd1` in the directory `<%PSModulePath%>\SampleModule`. (It doesn't matter which (user or global) module path is used).

This is enough for PowerShell to list my new module with the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` command.

In the next step I try to fill the manifest and set the `ModuleToProcess` property to an assembly, which is located in another directory. Calling `Import-Module` fails, PowerShell cannot find the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Get-Module` cmdlet with the `-ListAvailable` parameter works nice. The problem was the architecture, i.e. 32-bit PowerShell host could not list 64-bit modules...

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed.  In fact, I have a really nifty trick that does this for the SQL snapin.  The first chunk of the code is a function that will create a module manifest for you from one of of the module locations.  It will still prompt you (as the New-ModuleManifest cmdlet does) for some required parameters, like description.  It finds any types and format files, as well any .dll's named *.ps*.dll (most snapins follow this convention), and then it creates a module manifest that wraps the original module.  The second chunk of code does this specificially for the SQL PSSnapin.

```
function New-ModuleManifestFromSnapIn {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [System.String]
    ${Path},

    # The location in the filesystem where the V1 snapin resides
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.String]
    ${OriginalPath},

    [System.Guid]
    ${Guid},

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [System.String]
    ${Author},

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [System.String]
    ${CompanyName},

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [System.String]
    ${Copyright},

    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Version]
    ${ModuleVersion},

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [System.String]
    ${Description},

    [System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture]
    ${ProcessorArchitecture},

    [System.Version]
    ${PowerShellVersion},

    [System.Version]
    ${ClrVersion},

    [System.Version]
    ${DotNetFrameworkVersion},

    [System.String]
    ${PowerShellHostName},

    [System.Version]
    ${PowerShellHostVersion},

    [System.Object[]]
    ${RequiredModules},

    [AllowEmptyCollection()]
    [System.String[]]
    ${ScriptsToProcess},

    [AllowEmptyCollection()]
    [System.Object[]]
    ${ModuleList},

    [AllowNull()]
    [System.Object]
    ${PrivateData},

    [Switch]
    ${PassThru}
    )

    process {
        $types = Get-ChildItem $originalPath -Filter *.types.ps1xml
        $formats = Get-ChildItem $originalPath -Filter *.format.ps1xml
        $dlls = Get-ChildItem $originalPath -Filter *.ps*.dll
        $null = $psBoundParameters.Remove("OriginalPath")
        $psBoundParameters += @{
            VariablesToExport = "*"
            FunctionsToExport = "*"
            AliasesToExport = "*"
            CmdletsToExport = "*"
            FileList = @()
            RequiredAssemblies = @()
            ModuleToProcess = ""
            NestedModules = @($dlls | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
            TypesToProcess = @($types | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
            FormatsToProcess = @($formats | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
        }
        New-ModuleManifest @psBoundParameters
    }
}
```

This chunk will show create a manifest by pointing the tool @ SQL.

```
$basePath = $env:SqlSamplesSourceDataPath | Split-Path
if (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}) {
    $basePath = $basePath.Replace($env:ProgramFiles, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)})
} 

$path = Join-Path $basePath "Binn"


$basicMetaData = @{
    Author = "Microsoft Corporation"
    Description = "A Manifest to enable using the SQL PowerShell snapin in V2"
    CompanyName = "Microsoft Corporation"
    Copyright = (Get-Date).Year 
}
New-ModuleManifestFromSnapin -Path $psScriptRoot\Sql.psd1 -OriginalPath $path @BasicMetaData
```

The final chunk will copy any files named the current culture (i.e. SQL\en-us) into the module directory, which will make Get-Help work for the cmdlets.

This trick has worked for a few snapins, but may require some customizations for each snapin you want to re-expose as a module.  Luckily, this is a one time cost.

```
$Culture = Get-Culture
$CultureList = "$path\$culture", 
    (Join-Path $path $culture.ThreeLetterIsoLanguageName), 
    (Join-Path $path $culture.TwoLetterIsoLanguageName)

$CultureDirectory = Get-Item $CultureList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object -First 1 

if ($CultureDirectory) {
    $localDir = Join-Path $psScriptRoot (Split-Path $CultureDirectory -Leaf)
    $item = Get-Item $localDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    if ($item) {
        Remove-Item $item -Recurse -Force 
    }
    Copy-Item $CultureDirectory $LocalDir -Recurse
}
```

Hope this helps